# BlackBerry voip

Tags: blackberry, voip, sip

I want to make an application of voip dialer for BlackBerry. In which I have to make voip call.

Answer (score 1):

Linphone (open source), it has support for many OSes.

http://www.linphone.org/

To get the source code:
http://www.linphone.org/eng/download/git.html